# How can I redirect a query string, when it's already a semi-friendly url? ie. no index.php

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've spent so much time the last few days trying to work out some redirects.

I can do regular ones.. and indeed normal query string ones, where there is an index.php present in the url.

However, this url will not respond

```
http://www.bodysilk.co.uk/salon-products/dr-belter?category_id=6&page=shop.browse&limit=5&limitstart=0
```

I've tried detecting it with this, which is borrowing from another re-write which works ok... but does have an index.php in the non-sef url:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=shop.browse
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.bodysilk.co.uk/products/$1 [R=301,L]
```

How can I get it to act on the redirect? I have over 600 urls, which all have their own random unfriendly urls, and whilst I'm prety sure I can't redirect them all to their SEF equivalents, it would be good to at least forward them all on to the shop homepage or something? I'm sure google is hurting us a bit for the 600 404 errors in web master tools

If anyone can show me the way to do it... It would make my day as I'm pulling my hair out! None of the examples I try work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have issues here in RewriteCond matching. Instead of:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=shop.browse
```

It should be:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)page=shop\.browse(?:&|$) [NC]
```

Additionally your RewriteRule is also not correct looking at your example URL:

Currently you have:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.bodysilk.co.uk/products/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Which means your source URI has to be `/index.php` only with optional Query String.

I will suggest you to explain your requirement clearly so that you can better help.

Comment: Hi - I basically just want to collect all the bad urls in WMT, from before we had SEO plugin installed, and dump them on the "/products"   page, as this is the most relevant..

Bad urls-
http://www.bodysilk.co.uk/salon-products/dr-belter?category_id=6&page=shop.browse&limit=5&limitstart=0

http://www.bodysilk.co.uk/salon-products/dr-belter?category_id=6&page=shop.browse&limitstart=0&limit=5

Comment: Hmm if you want to capture all the bad URLs then its better to use a 404 handler.

Comment: You think that rather than redirect all these bad urls to the online shop, homepage.. I should just serve a 404 error document? THat is what I'm doing at the moment...If you see this url - http://www.bodysilk.co.uk/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=182

Is this what you mean by 404 handler?

Comment: By using 404 handler you can serve a 404 page but **more importantly** you can capture all those bad 404 URLs in a file or database in your 404 handler code (php or something else).

Comment: And what's the purpose of capturing all the bad 404 urls? I have a list of them in webmaster tools.... Why do I need another list? I appreciate your input

Comment: When I requested you to spell out your requirements you commented: `Hi - I basically just want to collect all the bad urls in WMT`. If it is not the case then please edit your question and explain your requirement clearly.

Comment: Ah. Sorry for the confusion. When I said 'collect' I meant... redirect. I wanted to resolve the errors in WMT basically.. as there are over 600 from old urls... and I just wanted to redirect them to the online shop homepage or something as I thought it was bad to have this many 404 errors in WMT?

Comment: If there are over 600 from old urls then it won't be easy to handle all of them using RewriteRule unless they are all following same pattern. It would still be better have your custom 404 handler and do a redirect to your home page conditionally from that custom handler.

Comment: Sorry to keep asking you, but do you mean just use a 404 error page, and then have a link on there saying - 'sorry, the page has moved - please click here if you would like to visit the shop pages' ? Is that what you mean by conditional redirect? Or do you mean something at server level?

Comment: Yes I meant at server level define a custom 404 handler eg: my-404.php. Then write some php code in my-404.php code to redirect to different user facing 404 page for different set of 404 URI's. If you're not comfortable in PHP then you can use any other server side programming language.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean :( Do you have a link to an article?

Comment: You can take a look here: http://bobpeers.com/technical/404_redirection or http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=php%20custom%20404%20handler&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&fp=776340e2d5abe540&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=776340e2d5abe540&biw=1680&bih=876"

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the ^ before page=shop.browse. The string does not start with page=shop.browse.

also make sure to escape the . otherwise shop(.)browse would work. ie: shop browse, shopAbrowse, etc...

try

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=shop\.browse
```